# CQRS: project out-of-order notifications in an ElasticSearch read model

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs

We have a microservice architecture and apply the CQRS pattern. A command sent to a microservice triggers an application state change and the emission of the corresponding event on our Kafka bus. We project these events in a read model built with ElasticSearch.

So far, so good.

Our microservices are eventually consistent with each other. But at any given time, they aren't (necessarily). Consequently, the events they send are not always consistent with each other either.

Moreover, to guarantee the coherence between an application state change and the emission of the corresponding event, we persist in DB the new state and the corresponding event in the same transaction (I am aware that we could use event sourcing and avoid persisting the state altogether). An asynchronous worker is then responsible to send these events on the Kafka bus. This pattern guarantees that at least one event will be sent for each state change (which is not an issue since our events are idempotent). However, since each microservice has its own event table and asynchronous worker, we cannot guarantee that events will be sent in the sequence in which the corresponding state changes occurred in their respective microservices.

EDIT: to clarify, each microservice has its own database, its own event table and its own worker. A specific worker processes the events in the order in which they were persisted in its corresponding event table, but different workers on different event tables, i.e. for distinct microservices, do not give such guarantee.

The problem arises when projecting these incoherent or out-of-sequence events from different microservices in the same ElasticSearch document.

A concrete example: let's imagine three different aggregates A, B and C (aggregate in the Domain Driven Design sense) managed by different microservices:

- There is a many-to-many relation between A and B. Aggregate A references the aggregate roots B he is bound to, but B is unaware of its relationships with A. When B is deleted, the microservice managing A listens for the corresponding event and undoes the binding of A with B.
- Similarily, there is a many-to-many relation between B and C. B knows of all related C aggregates, but the inverse is not true. When C is deleted, the microservice managing B listens for the corresponding event and undoes the binding of B with C.
- C has a property "name".

One of the use cases is to find, through ElasticSearch, all aggregates A that are bound to an aggregate B that is in turn bound to an aggregate C with a specific name.

As explained above, the separate event tables and workers could introduce variable delays between the emission of events from different microservices. Creating A, B and C and binding them together could for example result in the following sequence of events:

1. B created
2. B bound to C
3. C created with name XYZ
4. A created
5. A bound to B

Another example of batch of events: let's suppose we initially have aggregates B and C and two commands are issued simultaneously:

- delete C
- bind B to C

this could result in the events:

1. C deleted
2. B bound to C
3. B unbound from C (in response to event 1)

Concretely, we have trouble projecting these events in ElasticSearch document(s) because the events sometimes reference aggregates that do not exist anymore or do not exist yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "However, since each microservice has its own event table and asynchronous worker, we cannot guarantee that events will be sent in the sequence in which the corresponding state changes occurred in their respective microservices" - why? Doesn't the worker process the events in order they were persisted?

Comment: @Odsh Your problem seems to be that the indexer/projector isn't notified of events at the same time as other microservices are. That is, if I'm interpreting your sequence of events correctly - am I?

Comment: @Constantin, each microservice has its own database, its own event table and its own worker. A specific worker processes the events in the order in which they were persisted, but different workers on different event tables do not give such guarantee.

Comment: @Guillaume, I see what you mean. If the microservice managing B would only allow binding B to C if it had received the "C created" event and no "C deleted" event, then indeed the aforementioned sequence of events would only be possible if the indexer/projector received these events in a different sequence.
We don't do that kind of verification. But even if we did, unless microservices B and C posted their events in the same Kafka topic and partition (is that even possible/recommended?), I believe that yes, this can still happen.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Something bugs me though - How could B's microservice ever know that it should bind B to C if it didn't receive a "C created" event? That seems like an anomaly in an event-driven architecture.

Comment: *unless microservices B and C posted their events in the same Kafka topic and partition, I believe that yes, this can still happen* - then it could also happen between microservices, not only with the indexer, right?

Comment: @Guillaume: the way we do this is that we allow binding B to C in all cases, but upon receiving the "C deleted" event, we unbind B from C to restore consistency. That way, the microservice managing B does not need to keep track of all past events regarding C. Could this be an anti-pattern? As I see it, we could have a transient inconsistency between microservices, but eventually, consistency will be restored.

Comment: @Odsh Now I'm a bit confused why you added `C deleted` to the equation. Will give a shot at an answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the problem you raise is exclusive to the projection part of your system - it can also happen between microservices A, B and C.

Normally, the projector gets `C created` at the same time as B does. Only then can B bind itself to C, which makes it impossible for the specific order you mentioned to happen to the projector.

However, you're right to say that the messages could arrive in the wrong order if for instance, the network communication between B and C is considerably faster than between C and the projector.

I've never come across such a problem, but a few options come to mind :

- Don't enforce "foreign keys" at the read model level. Store B with its C reference even if you know very little about C for now. In other words, make `B bound to C` and `C created` commutative.
- Add a [causation ID](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/11/event-sourcing-microservices) to your events. This allows a client to recognize and deal with out of order messages. You can choose your own policy - reject, wait for causation event to arrive, try to process anyway, etc. That is not trivial to implement, though.
- Messaging platforms can guarantee ordering under certain conditions. You mentioned Kafka, under the same topic and partition. RabbitMQ, I think, has even stronger prerequisites.

  I'm not a messaging expert but it looks like the inter-microservice communication scenarios where it would be feasible are limited though. It also seems to go against the current trend in eventual consistency, where we tend to favor commutative operations (see CRDTs) over ensuring total order.

Comment: To clarify, in our solution, the aggregate B references the aggregate root of C it is bound to, but C is unaware of its binding with B. In other words, the microservice managing B also manages the binding to C. Furthermore, binding B to C is always allowed, even if C doesn't exist. However, the microservice managing C listens for these "B bound to C" events and, if C doesn't exist, emits an event to refute that binding. Upon receiving that last event, the binding is undone. Additionally, when C is deleted, the corresponding event also triggers the unbinding of B with C.

Comment: That's clearer, thanks. Not sure if that makes my answer irrelevant or not. And I still wonder how you could end up with the out-of-order sequence of events described in your Q aside from big message delivery delays in some parts of the system. Maybe a sequence diagram with components and messages exchanged would help.

Comment: The clarification was in regard to your assumption that B can only bind itself to C if it had previously received a "C created" event, which, with our current solution at least, is not true. But you are right that it doesn't explain the sequence of events I give in example, which is indeed purely a delay issue. That delay could be caused by the network but also by each service's event table and the speed at which each of those tables is emptied by its corresponding worker. I believe the causation ID is a good candidate to solve that particular issue, thank you (still thinking about it).

Comment: I added to the original question an example of batch of events that I think could happen, even if, as you suggested, B only allowed binding itself to C if it had previously received a "C created" without "C deleted" event, C only allowed to be deleted if it had never received a "B bound to C" without "B unbound from C" event and even if the read model received the events in the same sequence as the other services.

Comment: Btw I asked a question related to your suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554214/design-choice-for-a-microservice-event-driven-architecture/47555433#47555433).