# Design choice for a microservice event-driven architecture

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs

Let's suppose we have the following:

DDD aggregates A and B, A can reference B.

A microservice managing A that exposes the following commands:

- create A
- delete A
- link A to B
- unlink A from B

A microservice managing B that exposes the following commands:

- create B
- delete B

A successful creation, deletion, link or unlink always results in the emission of a corresponding event by the microservice that performed the action.

What is the best way to design an event-driven architecture for these two microservices so that:

1. A and B will always eventually be consistent with each other. By consistency, I mean A should not reference B if B doesn't exist.
2. The events from both microservices can easily be projected in a separate read model on which queries spanning both A and B can be made

Specifically, the following examples could lead to transient inconsistent states, but consistency must in all cases eventually be restored:

**Example 1**

- Initial consistent state: A exists, B doesn't, A is not linked to B
- Command: link A to B

**Example 2**

- Initial consistent state: A exists, B exists, A is linked to B
- Command: delete B

**Example 3**

- Initial consistent state: A exists, B exists, A is not linked to B
- Two simultaneous commands: link A to B and delete B

I have two solutions in mind.

**Solution 1**

- Microservice A only allows linking A to B if it has previously received a "B created" event and no "B deleted" event.
- Microservice B only allows deleting B if it has not previously received a "A linked to B" event, or if that event was followed by a "A unlinked from B" event.
- Microservice A listens to "B deleted" events and, upon receiving such an event, unlinks A from B (for the race condition in which B is deleted before it has received the A linked to B event).

**Solution 2:**

- Microservice A always allows linking A to B.
- Microservice B listens for "A linked to B" events and, upon receiving such an event, verifies that B exists. If it doesn't, it emits a "link to B refused" event.
- Microservice A listens for "B deleted" and "link to B refused" events and, upon receiving such an event, unlinks A from B.

**EDIT: Solution 3, proposed by Guillaume:**

- Microservice A only allows linking A to B if it has not previously received a  "B deleted" event.
- Microservice B always allows deleting B.
- Microservice A listens to "B deleted" events and, upon receiving such an event, unlinks A from B.

The advantage I see for solution 2 is that the microservices don't need to keep track of of past events emitted by the other service. In solution 1, basically each microservice has to maintain a read model of the other one.

A potential disadvantage for solution 2 could maybe be the added complexity of projecting these events in the read model, especially if more microservices and aggregates following the same pattern are added to the system.

Are there other (dis)advantages to one or the other solution, or even an anti-pattern I'm not aware of that should be avoided at all costs?
Is there a better solution than the two I propose?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> Microservice A only allows linking A to B if it has previously received a "B created" event and no "B deleted" event.

There's a potential problem here; consider a race between two messages, `link A to B` and `B Created`.  If the `B Created` message happens to arrive first, then everything links up as expected.  If `B Created` happens to arrive second, then the link doesn't happen.  In short, you have a business behavior that depends on your message plumbing.

[Udi Dahan, 2010](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/)

> A microsecond difference in timing shouldn’t make a difference to core business behaviors.
>
> A potential disadvantage for solution 2 could maybe be the added complexity of projecting these events in the read model, especially if more microservices and aggregates following the same pattern are added to the system.

I don't like that complexity at all; it sounds like a lot of work for not very much business value.

Exception Reports might be a viable alternative.  [Greg Young talked about this in 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=12m30s).  In short; having a monitor that detects inconsistent states, and the remediation of those states, may be enough.

Adding *automated* remediation comes later.  [Rinat Abdullin described](https://abdullin.com/post/ddd-evolving-business-processes-a-la-lokad/) this progression really well.

The automated version ends up looking something like solution 2; but with separation of the responsibilities -- the remediation logic lives outside of microservice A and B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer VoiceOfUnreason. Indeed, I can see that solution 1 is really problematic, thanks for pointing that out. I'm still reading your other comments and the links you provide. I agree that it is hard to see the business value of my example, but I wanted to provide a simplified view of a much more complex solution and make the abstraction of everything not directly related to the problem at hand. In all generality, it seems to me that the situation I expose could arise sooner or later in any microservice architecture.

Comment: As a rule: it's difficult to get good advice on domain-driven-designs when you try to abstract away the specifics of the domain.  Almost all of the really good lessons come from talking about the different problems/solutions in a _real_ model.

Answer (score 2):

Your solutions seem OK but there are some things that need to be clarified:

In DDD, aggregates are consistencies boundaries. An Aggregate is always in a consistent state, no matter what command it receives and if that command succeeds or not. But this does not mean that the whole system is in a permitted permanent state from the business point of view. There are moments when the system as whole is in a not-permitted state. This is OK as long as *eventually* it will transition in a permitted state. Here comes the **[Saga/Process managers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx)**. This is exactly their role: to bring the system in a valid state. They could be deployed as separate microservices.

One other type of component/pattern that I used in my CQRS projects are **Eventually-consistent command validators**. They validate a command (and reject it if it is not *valid*) before it reaches the Aggregate using a private read-model. These components minimize the situations when the system enters an invalid state and they complement the Sagas. They should be deployed inside the microservice that contains the Aggregate, as a layer on top of the domain layer (aggregate).

Now, back to Earth. Your solutions are a combination of Aggregates, Sagas and Eventually-consistent command validations.

> Solution 1
>
> - Microservice A only allows linking A to B if it has previously received a "B created" event and no "B deleted" event.
> - Microservice A listens to "B deleted" events and, upon receiving such an event, unlinks A from B.

In this architecture, Microservice A contains `Aggregate A` and a `Command validator` and Microservice B contains `Aggregate B` and a `Saga`. Here is important to understand that the validator would not prevent the system's invalid state but only would reduce the probability.

> Solution 2:
>
> - Microservice A always allows linking A to B.
> - Microservice B listens for "A linked to B" events and, upon receiving such an event, verifies that B exists. If it doesn't, it
>     emits a "link to B refused" event.
> - Microservice A listens for "B deleted" and "link to B refused" events and, upon receiving such an event, unlinks A from B.

In this architecture, Microservice A contains `Aggregate A` and a Saga and `Microservice B` contains `Aggregate B` and also a Saga. This solution could be simplified if the Saga on B would verify the *existence* of B and send `Unlink B from A` command to A instead of yielding an event.

In any case, in order to apply the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), you could extract the Sagas to their own microservices. In this case you would have a microservice per Aggregate and per Saga.

Comment: Thank you Constantin and for pointing out the presence of sagas and eventually-consistent command validators. As VoiceOfUnreason explained though, that eventually-consistent command validator would cause problems by rejecting valid commands precisely because it is not immediately consistent. I also take note of your suggestion to replace the "link to B refused" event by an "unlink B from A" command. The reason for the event was that it seemed odd for an aggregate to command another aggregate. But since it is the saga's responibility, potentially hosted in its own microservice, all is well.

Comment: indeed, that point from @VoiceOfUnreason is interesant but there are cases when this kind of validators is OK, for example when checking authorization inside the local microservice: you won't EVER permit an action of an unauthorized user even it is done in a eventuality consistent manner.

Comment: duly noted, thanks. I am curious: you allow a saga to send messages to other microservices, for example "Unlink B from A", instead of relying on events. Would you allows this for a command validator too? Specifically, if a microservice exposes an immediately consistent read model of the aggregate he manages, is it ok for a validator in another microservice to send a query command to that microservice to access its read model and thus become an "immediately consistent" command validator instead of an "eventually consistent" command validator?

Comment: @Odsh yes, it would be OK for a command validator to access another MSs read model, as long as you keep in mind that it is always eventually consistent (no matter how fast it is kept in sync). I.e. you should not use such a validator for checking the balance of a bank account before you allow the withdraw. (Edited)

Comment: I edited my previous comment as I made a mistake assuming Event sourcing. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I will start with the same premise as @ConstantinGalbenu but follow with a different proposition ;)

> Eventual consistency means that the whole system will eventually
>   *converge* to a consistent state.

If you add to that *"no matter the order in which messages are received"*, you've got a very strong statement by which your system will naturally tend to an ultimate coherent state without the help of an external process manager/saga.

If you make a maximum number of operations commutative from the receiver's perspective, e.g. it doesn't matter if `link A to B` arrives before or after `create A` (they both lead to the same resulting state), you're pretty much there. That's basically the first bullet point of Solution 2 generalized to a maximum of events, but not the second bullet point.

> - Microservice B listens for "A linked to B" events and, upon receiving
>     such an event, verifies that B exists. If it doesn't, it emits a "link
>     to B refused" event.

You don't need to do this in a nominal case. You'd do it in the case where you know that A didn't receive a `B deleted` message. But then it shouldn't be part of your normal business process, that's delivery failure management at the messaging platform level. I wouldn't put this kind of systematic double-check of everything by the microservice where the original data came from, because things get way too complex. It looks as if you're trying to put some immediate consistency back into an eventually consistent setup.

That solution might not always be feasible, but at least from the point of view of a passive read model that doesn't emit events in response to other events, I can't think of a case where you couldn't manage to handle all events in a commutative way.

Comment: thank you for your response. You mention that I don't need to send a "link to B refused" event, i.e. that solution 2 would work without its second bullet point. In that case, suppose for example that I send a command "link A to B" for a B that never existed. How will the system converge to a consistent state?

Comment: Where would B's identifier come from if B never existed?

Comment: fair enough. How about an identifier of B that has been deleted and for which the "B deleted" event has already been received by microservice A in the past?

Comment: I can see you're playing a bit of devil's advocate here since you wrote in a previous comment (to another Q) *"the way we do this is that we allow binding B to C in all cases"* :) But that's an interesting point. A microservice can only make decisions based on its own state and events it received before. Binding yourself to an entity you know doesn't exist any more over at the originating microservice is irrational behavior. To me, converging to a consistent state only works if each actor rationally synchronizes itself with what happens in the system.

Comment: I mean, if you go that way, a microservice could pretty much ignore an `X created` event it received and decide to treat it as a `Y created` instead. Then it's not cooperating, it's doing its own thing on the side. You can't consider it as a part of the "system that's trying to converge to a consistent state" IMO.

Comment: I think your solution differs from the two I proposed. I added a third one to reflect that. I.M.O. a only drawback to that solution is that you have to keep track of previously received events.